# R alternatives to JAGS/BUGS

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, hidden-markov-model, gibbs, jags

I've recently fit more complex hidden markov models with random effects and covariates etc. JAGS was the only program that could get the job done. Now I want to write my own functions to facilitate model specification etc. Is there an R-Package I could use for Bayesian parameter estimation as an alternative to JAGS? I found an old question regarding JAGS/BUGS alternatives in R, however, the last post is already 9 years old. So maybe there are new and flexible gibbs sampling packages available in R...?

Comment: Have you heard of Stan?

Comment: I have heard of it but haven't tried it yet. I will read up on it. However, I am actually looking for R packages that do the job.

Comment: Stan can be accessed through its R interface, rstan.

Comment: That's great and I will definitely check it out. But still it requires me to specify the model in stan language. That's the same issue I have with jags or bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the most powerful Bayesian package presently available in `R` is the `RStan` package (which has a whole website [here](https://mc-stan.org/users/interfaces/rstan)).  This pacakage uses a powerful method of MCMC integration called Hamiltonian Monte-Carlo, and a variant called the NUTS sampler (see [here](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_21/reference-manual/hmc-chapter.html)).  The package requires you to learn some syntax for model specification, but it is relatively simple to use, is very powerful, and gives information on convergence of MCMC chains for fitting the models.

Answer (score 2):

Nimble (https://r-nimble.org/) is a program that allows you define your model ala BUGS syntax. With Nimble, not only can you these models into pre-canned samplers (such as with JAGS, Stan, etc.), but you can also mix and match samplers and even write your own!

Admission of bias: I once worked on this project, although these days I'm not more than a user.